# How to add/multiply/subtract/divide/modulus two arbitrarily large numbers for an arbitrarily large result? Or in specific, how does BC manage it?

Tags: c, math

Only functions allowed are write and malloc.

I need to be able to calculate something like `45645646554665466546546456456448798789456456465789745321321231231231231231231231231321231321231321231467 * 45645646554665466546546456456448798789456456465789745321321231231231231231231231231321231321231321231467 - (4564564655466546654654645645644879878945645646578974532132123123123123123123123123132123132123132123146745645646554665466546546456456448798789456456465789745321321231231231231231231231231321231321231321231467 + 456456465546654665465464564564487987894564564657897453213212312312312312312312312313212313212313212314674564564655466546654654645645644879878945645646578974532132123123123123123123123123132123132123132123146745645646554665466546546456456448798789456456465789745321321231231231231231231231231321231321231321231467)`

How would I go about doing this(and in arbitrary bases to boot, ie. up to base 128 if necessary).

I'm thinking addition/subtraction/multiplication won't be too bad, just very tedious, but it seems like modulus/division will be trouble.

Comment: I've already done the "easy" parts. I've made a recursive descent parser to evaluate the expression, a function to evaluate the result and to convert it to whatever base I wish(up to 16 for now), but now I'll need to change everything to handle infinitely large inputs that won't fit in a long long as well as extremely large results. I'm thinking of making functions for each, and I'm thinking of a linked list or array to do addition/subtraction/multiplication, but while I'm working on validation to ensure the expression is valid, I'd like to see if there are more efficient ways to tackle it.

Comment: Perhaps you can use some library like GMP.

Comment: No external libraries are allowed. Read to read the input from stdin, write to output the result and error messages, malloc, and free are the only functions permitted for the assignment.

Comment: By the way, in a deleted answer on the link I provided above was a reference to [this C program](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/392/programs/bignum.c) which may or may not be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was searching up methods to do it with a string/struct, but I never really considered anything else as I was googling. Arbitrary-precision arithmetic seems like an exact answer to my question provided I can only do it with the 4 functions provided, and that C program seems to be a good reference. Thank you.